# Twilio: Too many "Error 30008" when sending messages

Tags: twilio, twiliosms

I have use Twilio for Programmable Messaging, sending sms, and from some point almost all of my requests had failed with **30008** error code - **Unknown error**. After trying multiple times to resend the message it seems to work, but after that a lot are crashing again. I've tested with multiple phone numbers it has the same behaviour. Does anyone have any ideas what should i do?

I've tried to find a solution on the documentation but for that error code there is nothing i can do. Ideas for some workarounds are more that welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to the fact that i had and url inside the message. Removing it seems to solve the problem.